# Powershell script guidance

Tags: powershell

I am looking for powershell code for installing software packages in remote machines which are in ADS domain.While installing I have to pass my admin credentials. How can I do this?
Guidance required

Comment: What part are you currently stuck on? Where is your PowerShell script so we can help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your password to be used on a remote computer using the `Get-Credential` command like this:

```
`$Credential = Get-Credential
```

You'll see a prompt like this appear:

[image]

I would recommend storing the applications you need to install in a central place, that all of your remote devices can reach.  I'll assume you've stored them in the UNC Path: `\\FileServer\Application`

Let's say you wanted to install 7Zip and had it present in that path:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Computers = 'RemotePC1', 'RemotePC2'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -Credential $Credential `
  -ScriptBlock {& \\FileServer\Application\7Zip.msi} -ArgumentList '/q INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\7-Zip"'
```

Comment: Sir I am a learner in this area and not known much yet. I request you to please provide a complete code so that I can try

Comment: Try at least this and let me know how it works for you :)